# Cannot delete the row from database using ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I have list of records. I want to delete a record by clicking on it, but when I use this `$.ajax()` function it removes the row but does not delete from the database.

**html code**

```
<tbody>
      <tr class="gradeX odd">
        <td class="sorting_1">2</td>
        <td class=" ">test</td>
        <td class=" ">test</td>
        <td class="center ">0</td>
        <td class="center ">Active</td>
        <td class=" "><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" name="editRecord"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="2" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gradeX even">
        <td class="sorting_1">3</td>
        <td class=" ">sarees</td>
        <td class=" ">contains sarres</td>
        <td cl="center ">1</td>
        <td class="center ">Active</td>
        <td class=" "><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" name="editRecord"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-circle" id="3" name="deleteRecord"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[name="deleteRecord"]', function(){

     var id= $(this).attr('id');
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function(data)
                   { 
                    console.log(data);  
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }

 });
```

**php code**

```
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
if($mode=='delete_category')
{    

   $id=$_POST['id'];
   $q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
   if($q){ echo "yes";}
   else{ echo "no";}

}
```

Comment: try `var data['id']= id;` instead of `var data = 'id=' + id ;`, the data node expects key-value pairs. You may also check the received POST values using `print_r($_POST);` in your receiving PHP script.

Comment: Another idea: which data type does `category_id` have? If it is of type INTEGER, using single quotes around its value will cause an error instead of deleting the row from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax(mode and id as get vars):

```
$.ajax(
        {
               type: "GET",
               url: "admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category&id="+id, 
               cache: false,
               success: function(data)
               { 
                console.log(data);  
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
               }
         });
```

Php:

```
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
if($mode=='delete_category')
{    

$id=$_GET['id'];
$q=$db->query("DELETE FROM db_category WHERE category_id='".$id."'");
if($q)
{ echo "yes";
}
else
{ echo "no";
}

}
```

Comment: tried get method , but it does not delete the row and console.log(data) output whole html page.

Answer (score 0):

Send the parameter "mode" with the variable "data" and only use $ _POST to retrieve the values​​. Thus the parameter "URL" will only have the value "admin_operation.php" and the variable "data" will contain:

```
var data = 'id =' + id + '&mode=delete_category';
```

Example:

```
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var data = 'id=' + id + '&mode=delete_category';
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        $.ajax(
        {
               type: "POST",
               url: "admin_operation.php",
               data: data,
               cache: false,

               success: function(data)
               { 
                console.log(data);  
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
               }
         });
```

Answer (score -1):

You are telling PHP to get parameters both from GET and POST. Your form is sending as GET. So as it is, your code is not executing the SQL statement because $id is blank.

You need to change it to only use GET since that's what you are sending on your form.

```
  $id=$_GET['id'];
```

Also, your Javascript is removing the line because you are not validating on the server if the line was removed or not. Make sure you check that.

```
   $.ajax(
        {
               type: "GET",
               url: "admin_operation.php?mode=delete_category",
               data: data,
               cache: false,

               success: function(data)
               { 
                console.log(data);  
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
               }
         });
```

Comment: That's wrong because the mode parameter is passed as URL variable (GET), not as part of the form.